# select rows if their elements form all possible pairs between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c'],'col2':['x','y','x','y','x']})
```

I'd like to select those rows that for each letter in `col1` forms all possible pairs with the letters of `col2`.
In this example that should be

```
  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    a    y
2    b    x
3    b    y
```

because the pair `[c y]` is missing.

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") . We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: @itprorh66, what is wrong with my example? If you copy and paste don't you get the data frame like the above (with the additional c x row)?

Comment: Are pandas function mandatory ? It seems easier to obtain from the `itertools` module ?

Comment: I have a question did a row like `a   x` can appear more than one time?

Comment: Please re-read what constitutes a Minimal Reproducible example.  Where is your coding attempt?

Comment: @EitanRosati, yes, in my real data frame it can because I have other columns that make rows unique

Comment: @hpchavaz no, not necessarily. How would you do it with itertools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try crosstab to find combinations, check for existence with `all`, then use `isin` to slice:

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2).eq(1).all(1)
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    a    y
2    b    x
3    b    y
```

Answer (score 0):

@Quang Hoang show how to do it in pure Pandas but going back to 'plain' Python seams easier (for me in any case). However the proposed solution calls in end to `query` to filter the dataframe.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c'],'col2':['x','y','x','y','x']})

l1, l2 = list(df['col1']), list(df['col2']) # extract from dataframe
l2set = set(l2)                             # set of col2 values

# build dictionary giving for col1 value, the list of col2 values
d = defaultdict(list)                                          
for e1, e2 in zip(l1, l2):
    d[e1].append(e2)

# get the list of acceptable values for which the set of col2 values is equal to the set of all col2 values
accept = [k for k,v in d.items() if set(v) == l2set]

#use query to filter data frame for 'accept' list
df2 = df.query('col1 in @accept')
```

DF2:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    a    y
2    b    x
3    b    y
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question, you can find the number of unique values (which should be two in this case), filter for rows that are equal to 2, and exclude the rest:

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('col1').col2.transform('nunique') == 2]

  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    a    y
2    b    x
3    b    y
```